# Creating a csv files from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
 x = {'A1':{'day1':{'feature1':20, 'feature2':40}},
      'A2':{'day2':{'feature1':50, 'feature2':70}}}
```

I want to be able to write this dictionary to a csv like this:

```
     day1, day2
 a1, 20,   40
 a2, 50,   70
```

Is it possible to use the python csv module to create this?

Comment: Nothing automatic for such a structure. One potential "shortcut" is to extract columns and column names from the structure into a pandas DataFrame and write a CSV from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, given that you write a function to iterate the dictionaries. Your data structure is confusing though, do you know how you would map it to CSV by hand (other than visually)?

One other thing to note is that dictionary keys will have no specific order to each other, so you will need to know how those are going to be ordered in the final CSV output. For example, feature1 may appear before OR after feature2 in x.keys()